# Issue when submitting a big form

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, tomcat

**EDIT:**

It looks like I've made a lot of mistakes.

First, it seems that the problem didn't occur only in IE ( I must have failed during my tests)

Secondly, putting **maxPostSize = -1** solved the problem. I changed both server.xml (the one on the apache-tomcat folder and the one pointing to the server's config of the server created via Eclipse)

Sorry again with my bad explanations. Thanks again for helping me.

---

I have an issue when trying to submit a form which contains an input with a big value (~1M characters).

```html
<form id="whatever" method="post" action="'+url+'" accept-charset="utf-8"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"' + this.target + '>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever2" id="whatever2" />
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById(whatever).submit();
```

```java
req.getParameter("whatever2");
```

When trying to obtain the parameter's value (whatever2) on server's side (doPost), it returns null when it is big (over 1 million characters) but works well when it contains less characters.

There is no problem when assigning the value but it seems that this one is not sent (no JS error)
This issue only appears on IE (using Quirks Mode), no problem using Mozilla Firefox.

**Configuration:**

- Client : JavaScript
- Server : Apache Tomcat / Java

Thus, is there some special limit even though I am using POST? Is there some parameter to change on the server or some JavaScript line to add to avoid this? Tell me if I forgot to mention some information.

Edit: The issue doesn't appear

Comment: Try using a tool like fiddler to test if the large form content is actually being sent to the server

Comment: I am not able to repro this. Can you create a small demo that shows the problem, share with us which version of IE you're testing against, and also check your `maxPostSize` in Tomcat's config?

Comment: So i am testing on IE9 (Quirks mode).

I've never used fiddler before so I tried and I see all my parameters in "Inspectors/WebForms" when I trigger the submit. Was it the test to do?

I did put maxPostSize = 0 on my tomcat (server.xml) for the good port but sadly it didn't change anything.

Thanks for your replies.